# Meteor method not found in React (404)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, methods

I'm having a hard time trying to integrate React into Meteor and something really weird is happening.

I have a component from which I'm invoking a Meteor method, I'm just doing some testing first to see if everything works as expected (it worked when I was using Blaze) but I get (besides the expected failure) a `Method '[meteor method name]' not found` with a `404` right after the Meteor method call.

**The error:**

```
---------------prev-inv
meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:932 Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'cloudinaryImageContents.insert' _class {error: "validation-error", reason: ""name" is required", details: Array(1), message: ""name" is required [validation-error]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…} Error
    at new _class (http://localhost:3001/packages/mdg_validation-error.js?hash=c824fee078386259563451e9fa961549731965f5:71:89)
    at throwError (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:10660:17)
    at Validator.validate (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:10691:11)
    at Object.Validators.(anonymous function) [as required] (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:10707:19)
    at ScalarField.validate (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:2411:20)
    at ScalarField.validate (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:2807:33)
    at http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:11584:13
    at catchValidationError (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:11513:7)
    at http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:11582:5
    at arrayEach (http://localhost:3001/packages/jagi_astronomy.js?hash=e399f2032bcf4df1ed57f144d7ebec90df5fdd3f:13376:11)
ImageContentAddPage.jsx:26 ---------------after-inv
ImageContentAddPage.jsx:23 errorClass {error: 404, reason: "Method 'cloudinaryImageContents.insert' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method 'cloudinaryImageContents.insert' not found [404]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…} undefined
ImageContentAddPage.jsx:24 -----inv
```

**The component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import PageSection from '/imports/ui/components/Misc/PageSection';
import ImageUploaderMiddleware from '/imports/ui/components/Middleware/ImageUploaderMiddleware';
import CreatorMiddleware from '/imports/ui/components/Middleware/CreatorMiddleware';

import '/imports/api/contents/images/CloudinaryImage/methods.js';

export default class ImageContentAddPage extends CreatorMiddleware {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
      path: '/some/path',
      methodName: 'cloudinaryImageContents.insert',
      data: {}
    });
  }

  handleCreate(){
    console.log('---------------prev-inv');
    Meteor.call( this.state.methodName, this.state.data, function(err, res){
      console.log(err, res);
      console.log('-----inv');
    });
    console.log('---------------after-inv');
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField hintText="Image name" floatingLabelText="Name" />
        <TextField hintText="Image description" floatingLabelText="Description" />
        <ImageUploaderMiddleware>
        <RaisedButton label="Upload" primary />
        </ImageUploaderMiddleware>
        <div>
          {this.state.error ? this.state.error.reason : null}
        </div>
        <RaisedButton label="Create" primary onTouchTap={this.handleCreate.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**The Meteor method:**

```
Meteor.methods({
  'cloudinaryImageContents.insert'(image){
    image = image || {};
    image.userId = this.userId;
    let newImage = new CloudinaryImageContent(image);
    return newImage.save();
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file which defines the method is bundled on your server?

Comment: Per Meteor documentation everything I'm using in the /imports folder. See https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/security-with-methods

Comment: It does not mean that it is bundled (in fact, it means that it is not automatically bundled). You should import it from an entry point outside of `/imports` (typically in a `/server/main.js` file).

Comment: Indeed. You were right. Just imported the method file to my server entry point and it worked as expected. I was using a top level /collections folder before, but right now I'm doing a refactoring to /imports, that's why it was being imported before but once I moved things to the /imports folder it stopped working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `/imports` folder for your collections `API` and methods, make sure you **import** the methods file to your **server entry point** (`/server/main.js`), otherwise your methods will not be visible on the server side.